# Cryptolocker virus removal

Tags: encryption, virus, anti-virus, virus-removal

I am facing cryptolocker virus problem,

I have tried decryptcryptolocker website but it did not work. In the below link you will find an example encrypted file in my pc.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwHDkPOX-lRtV2E5QjVwc2w1eVU/edit

I also check some solutions online but couldn't find a cure. Can you help me solve the issue ?

(The problem screenshots can be found in google just by typing cryptolocker, the screens are same)

Comment: Restore from backup ? You DO have backups, don't you ?

Comment: @Stephane, we are currently doing backups, but a lot of files and a lot of users are infected, and not all the files do have back ups.

Comment: In some cases, undeletion utilities can recover the original file - but it is depending on the cryptolocker malware strain.

Comment: Turn off the computer's internet NOW, and delete all of the cryptolocker .exes. One strain of the cryptolocker virus I worked with continued to encrypt files as long as the computer had internet access. It is even safer to just turn off the PC to remove the infection via a live USB/CD

Answer (score 3):

I've got bad news for you - the files are lost, unless you've got a backup.
Cryptolocker uses proper crypto combination (RSA-2048 and AES), and it's done right, so you've got **very** little chance of recovering anything.

Answer (score -3):

There are two ways that i know of:

> 1. Boot in safe mode and run a  virus scan.  You can use emsisoft emergency kit
> 2. Get a rescue CD and Boot it From USB or CD and let it scan for a virus. You can use Rescue CD - F-Secure